# OkHttpClient With BasicAuthentication

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am Using Retrofit For Server Connection. I Have Basic Authentication For Security. I Have Tried Mostly but It shows as Unauthorized.

```
 retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ApiInterface.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
            .build();
```

getUnsafeOkHttpClient

```
  private static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
    try {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                    }
                }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.addInterceptor(new BasicAuthInterceptor("jazenetworks", "99c293349e603a8661464a68f80188e3c9d46637"));
        builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
        builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
        return okHttpClient;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Error
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Unauthorized, url=https://test.com?username=123&password=123}

BasicAuthInterceptor 
I have used this Class For Authentication

```
public class BasicAuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private String credentials;

public BasicAuthInterceptor(String user, String password) {
    this.credentials = Credentials.basic(user, password);
}

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    Request authenticatedRequest = request.newBuilder()
        .header("Authorization", credentials).build();
    Log.e("Authorization",chain.proceed(authenticatedRequest).toString());
    return chain.proceed(authenticatedRequest);
}
```

}

Comment: `BasicAuthInterceptor` what does this class do? Credentials should not be passed as query params

Comment: this class is for login check. The server has basic Authentication. Where to pass these codes in getUnsafeOkHttpClient() @TimCastelijns

Comment: I Have shown BasicAuthInterceptor. Please See and Give Suggestions

Answer (score 1):

i have found solution  please note this

```
private static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
    try {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                    }
                }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        okhttp3.Credentials.basic("username", "password");
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
        builder.addInterceptor(new BasicAuthInterceptor("username", "password"));
        builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
        return okHttpClient;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```